# What's the difference between a content header and a header?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

HttpRequestMessage

Has Content.Headers
and Headers

Why is that? when I google Http protocol online, I don't see anyone mentioning a content header and a normal header, there are only "headers"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation for MVC, WebAPI and System.Net.Http are appaling. See [HttpContentHeaders.ContentType Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders.contenttype%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

> Gets or sets {insert text here}.

Well-known content-specific headers are grouped under "content headers". It's just for convenience. There are headers like `content-type`, `content-length`, and so on, as seen in [HttpContentHeaders Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.headers.httpcontentheaders%28v=vs.118%29.aspx):

- Public property   Allow   Gets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentDisposition  Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentEncoding Gets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentLanguage Gets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentLength   Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentLocation Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentMD5  Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentRange    Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   ContentType Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   Expires Gets or sets {insert text here}.
- Public property   LastModified    Gets or sets {insert text here}.

Comment: So, what if I add a header to Content.Headers instead of adding it to the Headers property, does that actually make a different on the server side? or is it exactly the same request?

Comment: I don't know, and it isn't documented. You'll have to look at the source or just test it to be sure.

Comment: @SpaceMonkey, found this example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419333/2195138

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, content headers come into play when you are dealing with MultipartContent or MultipartFormDataContent. The example in this blog post explicity applies a "Content-Type" header at the content level.

http://dotnetcodr.com/2013/01/10/how-to-post-a-multipart-http-message-to-a-web-service-in-c-and-handle-it-with-java/