# What is the difference between request headers and content headers for HttpClient

Tags: c#, request, dotnet-httpclient, request-headers

Can anybody explain what is the difference between the request header and content header?

In this particular case I'm talking about UWP `HttpClient` object. First you create `HttpClient`, then you create `HttpRequestMessage` and then you assign, in my case `HttpStreamContent` to the Content property of the HttpRequest message. There is Headers property on the `HttpRequestMessage` and there is Headers property on the `HttpStreamContent`.

When should I use one or another?
Where exactly the headers will appear in one or another case?

Here is a code snippet to explain what I mean

```cs
using(var objProtocolFilter = new HttpBaseProtocolFilter()) {
    objProtocolFilter.AllowUI = false;
    objProtocolFilter.CacheControl.ReadBehavior = HttpCacheReadBehavior.NoCache;
    objProtocolFilter.CacheControl.WriteBehavior = HttpCacheWriteBehavior.NoCache;
    
    using(var objClient = new HttpClient(objProtocolFilter)) {
        HttpMethod eMethod = Method switch {
            HttpUploadMethod.Post => HttpMethod.Post,
            HttpUploadMethod.Put => HttpMethod.Put,
            _ => throw new ValueOutOfRangeException(nameof(Method))
        };
        
        using(var objRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(eMethod, RemoteUri)) {
            _Headers.Cast<string>().Execute(item => objRequest.Headers.TryAppendWithoutValidation(item, _Headers[item]));

            objRequest.Content = new HttpStreamContent(objInputStream.AsInputStream());
            _Headers.Cast<string>().Execute(item => objRequest.Content.Headers.TryAppendWithoutValidation(item, _Headers[item]));
            objRequest.Content.Headers.ContentLength = (ulong)objInputStream.Length;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I just add the same list of headers to `HttpRequestMessage` and to `HttStreamContent`. I guess it's wrong unless those objects are smart enough to apply only permitted headers in one or the other case. So, which headers should go where? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Theory

They serve different purpose:

- [HttpStreamContent.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpstreamcontent.headers) returns an [HttpContentHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httpcontentheadercollection?view=winrt-19041)

  - You can set things like: `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Range`, `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, etc.
  - In other words these are related to the request's body
- [HttpRequestMessage.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httprequestmessage.headers?view=winrt-19041) returns an [HttpRequestHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httprequestheadercollection?view=winrt-19041)

  - You can set things like: `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Authorization`, `Cookie`, etc.
  - In other words these are related to the request itself.
- +1: ([HttpResponseMessage.Headers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.httpresponsemessage.headers) returns an [HttpResponseHeaderCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.web.http.headers.httpresponseheadercollection))

## Practice

### Try to set Content-Type on the Request

```cs
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
request.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

This will produce the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'

### Try to set Accept on Content

```cs
var content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.Add("Accept","application/json");
```

This will produce the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'

### Try to set the same arbitrary header at both places:

```cs
const string headerKey = "A", requestHeaderValue = "B", contentHeaderValue = "C";

var content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.Add(headerKey, contentHeaderValue);

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
request.Headers.Add(headerKey, requestHeaderValue);
```

This will not produce any exception.

#### Which value is passed to the downstream?

In order to be able answer this question I will use the [WireMock.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WireMock.Net/) nuget package to run a mock server.

```cs
const string address = "http://localhost:9000", route = "/";
var server = WireMockServer.Start(new WireMockServerSettings { Urls = new[] { address } });

server
    .Given(Request.Create()
        .WithPath(route)
        .WithHeader(headerKey, new ExactMatcher(requestHeaderValue))
        .UsingPost())
    .RespondWith(Response.Create()
        .WithBody("From Request header")
        .WithStatusCode(200));

server
    .Given(Request.Create()
        .WithPath(route)
        .WithHeader(headerKey, new ExactMatcher(contentHeaderValue))
        .UsingPost())
    .RespondWith(Response
        .Create()
        .WithBody("From Content header")
        .WithStatusCode(200));
```

- Here I have defined a mock server which listens on the 9000 port
- It has a single endpoint on the `/` route and it anticipates a `POST` request
- Depending on the `headerKey` value it may respond

  - either with `From Request header`
  - or with `From Content header`

If I send a request where the same header key is set on both objects then I will receive the following response:

```
From Request header
```

#### Does ordering matter?

What if I switch the order of the header key assignments?

```cs
HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
request.Headers.Add(headerKey, requestHeaderValue);

var content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8);
content.Headers.Add(headerKey, contentHeaderValue);
```

The result will be the same: `From Request header`.

---

For the sake of completeness here is the full source code:

```cs
static readonly HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    const string headerKey = "A", requestHeaderValue = "B", contentHeaderValue = "C";
    const string address = "http://localhost:9000", route = "/";
    var server = WireMockServer.Start(new WireMockServerSettings { Urls = new[] { address } });

    server
        .Given(Request.Create()
            .WithPath(route)
            .WithHeader(headerKey, new ExactMatcher(requestHeaderValue))
            .UsingPost())
        .RespondWith(Response.Create()
            .WithBody("From Request header")
            .WithStatusCode(200));

    server
        .Given(Request.Create()
            .WithPath(route)
            .WithHeader(headerKey, new ExactMatcher(contentHeaderValue))
            .UsingPost())
        .RespondWith(Response
            .Create()
            .WithBody("From Content header")
            .WithStatusCode(200));

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address);
    request.Headers.Add(headerKey, requestHeaderValue);

    var content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8);
    content.Headers.Add(headerKey, contentHeaderValue);

    var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
    var headerSource = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(headerSource);
}
```

---

**UPDATE #1** Found a bug in my example

I've just realized that I forgot to use the `Content` property of the `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, address) { Content = content };
```

- If we set the same header in both places then the response will be: `{"Status":"No matching mapping found"}`
- If we set this header only on the content then the response will be: `From Content header`
- If we set this header only on the request then the response will be: `From Request header`

So, why did we receive this `No matching mapping found`? The reason is that because both values are sent in this case and there is no registered route for that case.

To prove the theory let's write some assessment code:

```
var logs = server.FindLogEntries(Request.Create().WithPath(route).UsingPost());
Console.WriteLine(logs.First().RequestMessage.Headers[headerKey].Count);
```

- After we have received the response from the server we can ask for the logs (via `FindLogEntries`)
- On a log entry we can access the request message so, we can scrutinize the headers
- As you can see the `A` header contains both values `B` and `C`

Comment: This looks like a semantic difference. If we talk about the raw request that is generated by the code, a request like that http://rebol.net/cookbook/recipes/0059.html all header items are passed as a single list, right? So, if I set Accept header for the HttpStreamContent and Content-Range for HttpRequestMessage, will it make a difference for the generated raw request? Or will those classes not allow this kind of things?

Comment: @Alex I've extended my answer where I've detailed my response to your new questions. Please check them.

Comment: @Alex Did my explanation make sense or do you need further clarity?

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you. I definitely got everything I needed.