# What is the .NET Core HttpRequest Headers priority?

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

Currently I am doing a http request sending task. I know we have different ways to add headers to the request.

1. `HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders`
2. `HttpRequestMessage.Headers`
3. `HttpContent.Headers`

If I have a custom header called A, which header collection of (1, 2, 3) should I insert the A to?

if (1,2), (1,3), OR (2,3) contains same key e.g. both 1 and 2 has "Host", what is the priority of them? will one replace others? or it will throw an exception?

Comment: A httpclient is meant to be reused, so `DefaultRequestHeaders` should be for default headers.

Comment: The default request headers (1) are request headers sent for ever request. (2) are the headers for that specific request. IIRC they don’t replace the default headers, but are additional as there can be multiple headers with the same key. (3) are headers which go into the HTTP content/body, not the HTTP request headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good question. Each of the `Headers` collection has a dedicated purpose (as it was mentioned by other commenters as well).

#### Purposes

- `DefaultRequestHeaders` can be used to set headers that are intended to be reused in multiple requests
- `Headers` of `HttpRequestMessage` can be used to set headers like `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, `Authorization`, `Cookie`, etc
- `Headers` of `HttpContent` can be used to set headers like `Content-Disposition`, `Content-Range`, `Content-Length`, `Content-Type`, etc.

#### Setting standard headers

Those headers that set on `DefaultRequestHeaders` can be overwritten by the `Headers` of `HttpRequestMessage` for an individual request.

If you try to set

- the `Content-Type` header on `HttpRequestMessage`
- or the `Accept` header on `HttpContent`

then you will receive an `InvalidOperationException`:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.'

#### Setting custom headers

If you try to set the same arbitrary (not standard) header on `HttpRequestMessage` and on `HttpContent` then both values will be sent.

---

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66419333/13268855) I have detailed this topic in a bit more depth.

Comment: Thank you Peter very much!! Really helpful!