# 403 Error using PostAsJsonAsync but Works in Postman

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to create a POST call using HttpClient that I have fully working in Postman. Here is the body I'm sending in Postman:

```
{
  "searchType": "games",
  "searchTerms": [
    "mario"
  ],
  "searchPage": 1,
  "size": 20,
  "searchOptions": {
    "games": {
      "userId": 0,
      "platform": "",
      "sortCategory": "popular",
      "rangeCategory": "main",
      "rangeTime": {
        "min": 0,
        "max": 0
      },
      "gameplay": {
        "perspective": "",
        "flow": "",
        "genre": ""
      },
      "modifier": ""
    },
    "users": {
      "sortCategory": "postcount"
    },
    "filter": "",
    "sort": 0,
    "randomizer": 0
  }
}
```

I have this written as the following in C#:

```
var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient(HttpClients.HowLongToBeat.ToString());
var request = new HowLongToBeatRequest
{
    SearchType = "games",
    SearchTerms = searchTerm.Trim().Split(" "),
    SearchPage = 1,
    Size = 20,
    SearchOptions = new SearchOptions
    {
        Games = new SearchOptionsGames
        {
            UserId = 0,
            Platform = "",
            SortCategory = "popular",
            RangeCategory = "main",
            RangeTime = new SearchOptionsGamesRangeTime
            {
                Min = 0,
                Max = 0
            },
            Gameplay = new SearchOptionsGamesGameplay
            {
                Perspective = "",
                Flow = "",
                Genre = ""
            },
            Modifier = ""
        },
        Users = new SearchOptionsUsers
        {
            SortCategory = "postcount"
        },
        Filter = "",
        Sort = 0,
        Randomizer = 0
    }
};

//var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(request);
//var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
//var response = await client.PostAsync("api/search", content);
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/search", request, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
});
return new HowLongToBeatResponse();
```

I have this set up as

The url I'm hitting is: `https://www.howlongtobeat.com/api/search` and I'm setting it up like so in my Startup.cs

```
services.AddHttpClient(HttpClients.HowLongToBeat.ToString(), config =>
{
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.howlongtobeat.com/");
    config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.howlongtobeat.com/");
});
```

I am passing this Referer header in my Postman collection as well.

Basically, I can't figure out why this code gets a 403 in C# but the Postman that I think is exactly the same is getting a successful response. Am I missing something?

Let me know if there's any missing info I can provide.

Comment: make sure  passing correct headers value

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that you can generate C# code from Postman? A side-by-side comparison could help you to spot the difference(s)

Comment: @PeterCsala unfortunately it only generates code with RestSharp so it's different enough that the comparison isn't showing any obvious differences from what I have.

Comment: Setting the headers and the url are not so different in the two approaches :) Most of the time there is only one missing header which is causing the problem.

Comment: @PeterCsala so the RestSharp approach adds a header I don't specify, `request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");`, but when I try adding this with `config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type","application/json");` I get the following error:  `Misused header name, 'Content-Type'. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects`

Comment: You should set that header on the HttpContent, not on the request. [For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74108146/13268855)

Comment: @PeterCsala I tried it like so, same response: 
            `var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(request), Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/search")
            {
                Content = content
            };

            var response = await client.SendAsync(httpRequest);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. The issue was that this specific API required a User Agent header specified.

Comment: I have mentioned it in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here, The BaseAddress property needs to be suffixed (https://www.howlongtobeat.com/) with a forward slash and here you already set route as well, change it to

```
services.AddHttpClient(HttpClients.HowLongToBeat.ToString(), config =>
{
    config.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.howlongtobeat.com/");
    config.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Referer", "https://www.howlongtobeat.com/api/search");
});
```

And then

```
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/search", request, new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase
});
```

**Updated:**

try this, here I have hard-coded the Base URL for testing purposes.

```
try
{

    var data_ = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root);
    var buffer_ = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data_);
    var byteContent_ = new ByteArrayContent(buffer_);
    byteContent_.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    string _urls = "https://www.howlongtobeat.com/api/search";
    var responses_ = await _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(_urls, byteContent_);

    if (responses_.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[GetPrimeryAccount] Response: Success");
        string body = await responses_.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); ;
}
```

Comment: Yeah sorry my mistake here was in filling in the base address and headers in the question with the url that included the path, sloppy copy/paste since in the code itself I just use the appsettings.json file to set those and have that set correctly. I've updated the question.

Comment: @muttley91 Try my updated code snippet, just for the client verication

Comment: No luck here either, same result.

Comment: @muttley91 what is the inner exception, please check if it it something related to the SSL

Answer (score 0):

### On HLTB API

I know this has already been resolved but in case anyone needed any pointers for making requests to HLTB API:

As the author mentioned

> The issue was that this specific API required a User Agent header specified.

However, as of June 2023 (quite possibly prior to that), to make calls to 'https://www.howlongtobeat.com/api/search' you need to have also set Header's:

- 'origin' to 'https://howlongtobeat.com' (or possibly other, just needs to be set)
- 'referer' to 'https://howlongtobeat.com' (same thing)

As For the body, you do not need to include the entire json as shown in the author's example, this is enough:

```
{"searchTerms":["The", "Witcher", "3"]}
```

For C# specifically, make sure there is no encoding on your StringContent (used for the request's body) and is of a type of 'application/json'.